Pac4j-Play Custom HttpErrorHandler not loading views
I have my own implementation of the interface HttpErrorHandler in a playframework java project. I managed to implement 4XX errors however the 403 & 401 views I created in CustomHttpErrorHandler don't show up because before reaching handler they go into Pac4j and rather my own pages. A blank white page is shown instead.
I can't put them in PlayHttpActionAdapter.INSTANCE.getResults().put() in security module, since I have to supply my views with the request and I don't have access to request in the CustomHttpErrorHandler class which implements HttpErrorHandler.
protected CompletionStage<Result> onForbidden(RequestHeader request, String message) {
    logger.debug("forbiden");
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
            forbidden(views.html.errors.error403.render(profileManagerService.getProfilesWithHeader(request, configu).getProfiles())));
}

protected CompletionStage<Result> onUnauthorized(RequestHeader request, String message) {
    logger.debug("unauthorized");
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
            unauthorized(views.html.errors.error401.render(profileManagerService.getProfilesWithHeader(request, configu).getProfiles())));
}

These two methods are called in the following code for each 401 and 403 codes.
public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) 

The 404 page shows up correctly so custom handler is likely set up correctly in config. However, the 401 and 403 are intercepted with pac4j in this class. Logs never get shown
How can I get my 401 and 403 pages to display properly?
#pac4j #playframework

I found answer to it.
I provided custom HttpActionAdabter use same code as PlayHttpActionAdabter
but add this code at the first of the adabt method
@Override
public Result adapt(final HttpAction action, final WebContext context) {
    Http.RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new Http.RequestBuilder();
    Http.Request request = requestBuilder.path(context.getPath()).build();
    logger.warn(request.toString());
    if(results.isEmpty()) {
        results.put(HttpConstants.UNAUTHORIZED, unauthorized(views.html.errors.error401.render(profileManagerService.getProfiles(request, SecurityModule.configu).getProfiles()).toString()).as((HttpConstants.HTML_CONTENT_TYPE)));
        results.put(HttpConstants.FORBIDDEN, forbidden(views.html.errors.error403.render(profileManagerService.getProfiles(request, SecurityModule.configu).getProfiles()).toString()).as((HttpConstants.HTML_CONTENT_TYPE)));
    }
    logger.warn(results.toString());

as you see i built a request with context getpath and it's enough for the purpose
Edit: alternatively you can put in results of actionadapter everytime you call a view from within controller
why i got here?
as in templates i have a main.scala.html which contains navbar and footer and templates for all pages, other views calls main. in navbar i have username which i get it from profiles, also i couldn't find the way to only supply username to only main.scala.html since in java play, there is no scalatemplathelper

pac4j is a security engine used for many Java environments: https://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html
So you have generic concepts like the HttpActionAdabter whose role is to turn a returned HttpAction into a specific framework (Play framework here) view.
Did you take a look at the demo https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo regarding the views?

Yes i used demo at the start, and i know what is pac4j! also i use playframwork java not scala so scala demo doesn't fit me.
